# Shell script to copy one file at a time in a cron job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have some csv files in location A like this

abc1.csv,
abc2.csv,
abc3.csv

I have a cron job which runs every 30 mins and in each execution I want to copy only 1 file(which shouldn't be repeated) and placed it in location B

I had though of 2 ways of doing this
1)I will pick the first file in the list of files and copy it to location B and will delete it once copied.Problem with this is I am not sure when the file will get copied completely and if i delete before its completed copied it can be an issue
2)I will have a temp folder.So i will copy the file from location A to location B and also keep it in temp location.In next iteration, when I pick the file from list of files I will compare its existence in the temp file location.If it exists I will move to next file .I think this will be more time consuming etc.

Please suggest if there is any other better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this bash script for your use case:

```
source="/path/to/.csv/directory"
dest="/path/to/destination/directory"

cd $source

for file in *.csv
do
        if [ ! -f $dest/"$file" ]
        then
                cp -v $file $dest
                break
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure you move the already copied file with:

```
cp abc1.csv destination/ && mv abc1.csv.done
```

(here you can make your logic to find only `*.csv`  files, and not take into account `*.done` files.. that have been already processed by your script... or use any suffix you want..

if the `cp` does not succeed, nothing after that will get executed, so the file will not be moved.

You can also replace `mv` with `rm` to delete it:

```
cp abc1.csv destination/ && rm -f abc1.csv
```

Further more, you can add to the above commands error messages in case you want to be informed if the `cp` failed:

```
cp abc1.csv destination/ && mv abc1.csv.done || echo "copy of file abc1.csv failed"
```

And get informed via CRON/email output

Answer (score 0):

Finally I took some idea from both the opted solution.Here is the final script

```
source="/path/to/.csv/directory"
dest="/path/to/destination/directory"

cd $source

for file in *.csv
do
        if [ ! -f $dest/"$file" ]
        then
                cp -v $file $dest || echo "copy of file $file failed"
                rm -f $file
                break
        fi
done
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the source file? This wasn't the part of your use case.

Comment: Yes not needed.But I am deleting so that i make sure that file is not picked by any chance even if the cron doesn't work fine,etc